# shell script works manually, but not with cron

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I've been scouring the internet for a solution, but I have a shell script I want to run that works fine from the `cli` but not from `cron`.

This works from my prompt: `sh ~/Applications/scripts/script.sh`

`crontab` entry:

```
* * * * * /home/user/Applications/scripts/script.sh
```

script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/myapp update &> /home/user/myapp_sh_update_stdout.log
/usr/local/bin/myapp run &> /home/user/myapp_sh_run_stdout.log
```

Thoughts?  Experiments with other answers are no good for me, so I am going specific to see what I could do differently.  Running it every minute to debug, but it will be run at a morning hour on one day of the week when confirmed working.

Comment: You need user there. `* * * * * root /home/user/Applications/scripts/script.sh`

Comment: @Pilot6 just to be clear, that's only the case for the system-wide `/etc/crontab`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&>` is a [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) - either change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` or change the redirections to

```
/usr/local/bin/myapp update > /home/user/myapp_sh_update_stdout.log  2>&1
/usr/local/bin/myapp run > /home/user/myapp_sh_run_stdout.log 2>&1
```